# How to add a value to the field of item in a list using Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class as

```
public class Student{
   private String name;
   private String school;

}
```

and a list of `Student` objects

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList();
```

suppose I have already populated the `name` field of each `Student` object.
Now I want to populate the school field of each object with the same value, say "XYZ school". How can I do this using Java 8 stream()?
I tried in following way but it gives error.

```
List<Student> xyzStudent = students.stream()
    .map(o -> o.setSchool("XYZ school"));
```

Should I use `map` there or something else? And how can I collect the the result in `xyzStudent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is nothing wrong with good old for each loop, even in java 8:

```
for (Student s : students) {
    s.setSchool("XYZ school");
}
```

You can use foreach terminal operation to achieve the same behaviour.

```
students.stream().forEach(s -> s.setSchool("XYZ school"));
```

Although some people say that operation done in forEach on a stream should not have side effects.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right . But i m trying my hand on java 8 . And this is the solution I wanted , Thank you @frant.hrtm

Comment: Note that for this operation you don't need `.stream()`. Use just `students.forEach(s -> s.setSchool("XYZ school"))`, which is shorter and has less overhead.

Comment: Your last statement (about side-effects in a forEach) is confused.  The operation in a forEach can have *nothing but* side-effects, because it can't return anything!